# How do I delete my Harvest Seniors account?

Tags: account-management

How do I delete my [Harvest Seniors](http://harvestseniors.com.au) account? I have tried every menu item there is and there is no contact. There was a chat online to a staff member but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://app2.harvestseniors.com/help/terms.cfm):

> You may terminate your Subscription at any time by requesting a cancellation of the Service through the online cancellation facility on the Site. Please find the cancellation details by clicking on the "Membership Page" under the "Account" link. Cancellation must be made at least 72 hours prior to your renewal date in order to ensure the automated re-billing process is stopped for the renewal term. Any cancellation that is made after such date will cancel the automated re-billing process for future renewal terms, but will not cancel the automated re-billing process for the pending renewal term. You will be responsible for paying membership fees for any renewal term that is not cancelled in accordance with this policy at least 72 hours prior to the renewal date. A request for termination under this clause does not give rise to any refund for any unused amounts of membership fees paid.

There is an email to contact [here](http://www.harvestagencies.com/lp/Dating.html) `support@harvestagencies.com`

Comment: I had no idea what this site was, so by the time I had researched it a bit, I found the answer.